# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a spring MVC project with hibernate. But every time I try to run it gives the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/MetadataSources;)V
```

I tried changing the dependencies. But nothing seems to work.

Here's my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.version>5.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.4.14.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.14.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here's my spring-config.xml

```
<!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedemo?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" /> 

    <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
</bean> 

<!-- Setup Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.bat.model" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I run it in tomcat, the welcome page comes without any issue. But when I try to fetch data from the database this error occurs. So I'm guessing this is a hibernate issue.

I am fairly new to spring and hibernate. So I might sound stupid. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here's my [entire stack trace](https://pastebin.com/RiAFanZf). (If I post it with the question it will be too long. That's why I used external link for this.)

Comment: Could you please share the entire stack trace ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I updated the question. Added the link to the entire stack trace.

Comment: seems like the versioning of hibernate libraries. Spring is looking for a different version than is available. Check the tomcat lib folders as well

Comment: no such method exception for init<> means you've forget to added the constructor without argument to the your classes. notice hibernate and spring use reflection to build some class and need  default constructor